# FB connect permission error in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, google-chrome, webview

Facebook started showing "Connection Error, Try again" error while new user should be asked to allow access basic information. This wasn't an issue two days ago and we have not made any changes to our code.

However, this error does not appear in desktop browser or mobile browser, only in webview.

Any suggestions what changed or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the webview [cache](http://file:///F:/SDK/android/docs/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29)?

Comment: Yes, including complete app wipe and reinstall.